# How can we run Javascript in C# applications?

Tags: c#, javascript

For example, if I'm using the OpenPGP implementation of Crypto-js ([PGEncode.js](http://code.google.com/p/snapbox/source/browse/trunk/+snapbox/crypt/hanewin/PGencode.js?r=2)) and I want to call this function in a C# application, is that possible? What kind of tool should I use?

Comment: Why not use the C# implementation of OpenPGP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Jurassic](http://jurassic.codeplex.com/).

> Jurassic is an implementation of the ECMAScript language and runtime. It aims to provide the best performing and most standards-compliant implementation of JavaScript for .NET. Jurassic is not intended for end-users; instead it is intended to be integrated into .NET programs. If you are the author of a .NET program, you can use Jurassic to compile and execute JavaScript code.